# Disable Wrapping Cursor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim, vi

I'm mostly using Vi (edit: Vim) for text editing and the viPlugin for Eclipse Juno. Eclipse seems to have a very annoying behaviour of "wrapping" the cursor to the next/previous line, if yout reach the end/start of a line through cursor keys.

(Reproduce by placing the cursor on the first position in a line and then press arrow-left. Cursor will be positioned on the end of the previous line)

I would think this behaviour is of very little use to programmers. We (mostly) think in lines, not in a flowing text.

So I would assume one could disable this annoying feature but I haven't found any related settings.

Any idea someone?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (not a `vi` user), but... when you put the cursor at the beginning of line `n` and hit the left arrow key, what do you expect to happen, other than the cursor going to the end of line `n-1`?

Comment: vi wraps.  Some vi-clones may provide left/right shifting as an alternative.  It sounds as if the viPlugin follows vi's behavior.

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have been more precise: I don't have any recent (as in "the last 20 years or so") experience with traditional vi. I'm using vim. Vim treats the said keystrokes as noop.

Comment: I've never known traditional vi to wrap.  Arrow keys (and the `h` and `l` commands) only move you within the current line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim, the behavior of the arrows when the cursor is at the BOL/EOL is governed by the `'whichwrap'` option which — judging by [the manual](http://www.viplugin.com/files/User_Manual_viPlugin.pdf) — is not supported by viPlugin.

What you want would be achievable with custom mappings and a bit of vimscript logic in Vim itself but I doubt it's doable in viPlugin.

Now, that plugin is payware so I suggest you contact the author and ask him to add `'whichwrap'` or provide a workaround.